# Distribution curves in ggplot2 raincloud plot display incorrectly

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot, violin-plot, ggridges

I noticed strange behaviour of the raincloud plot package in R. Specifically, **density** curves are sensitive to data **values** in some (but not all) cases. It seems that the shape of the distribution curve made by geom_flat_violin() is somehow linked to data values (where it shouldn't be), and I can't find how to restore their independence. The only clue I managed to find: the curves are shrunk based on the lowest values in the data, although shrinkage affects the whole panel where those values occur, not just the sub-group containing them.

Below is a reproducible example, and a link to its image output to show what I mean.
Just a note in advance: the raincloud package (presented in [This paper](https://wellcomeopenresearch.org/articles/4-63)) is not on CRAN afaik, so I lifted it directly from the authors' [github repo](https://github.com/jorvlan/raincloudplots/blob/main/R/geom_flat_violin.R). I also tried an [alternative source file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benmarwick/2a1bb0133ff568cbe28d/raw/fb53bd97121f7f9ce947837ef1a4c65a73bffb3f/geom_flat_violin.R) which reproduces the . Other implementations such as ggrdiges::geom_density_ridges() or {ggdist} didn't have the same level of control on graphic parameters (e.g. smoothing), unless I'm missing something.

Example code:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
source("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benmarwick/2a1bb0133ff568cbe28d/raw/fb53bd97121f7f9ce947837ef1a4c65a73bffb3f/geom_flat_violin.R")

# load data and melt into longform
data(iris)
miris <- melt(iris,id.vars = "Species", measure.vars = colnames(iris)[1:4], variable.name = "measurement")

## 1- plotting as is gives horizontally "squashed" curves in two of four panels
ggplot(miris, aes(x = Species, y = value, fill = Species)) +
    geom_flat_violin(position = position_nudge(x = .15, y = 0)) +
    facet_wrap(~measurement) 

## 2- manipulating the group of smallest values seems to fix the relevant panel (but fixing other groups doesn't fix the problem - I tried that) 
airis <- miris
# get indices of data to manipulate
inds <- intersect(which(airis$Species == "setosa"), which(airis$measurement == "Petal.Width"))
# assign larger values
airis$value[inds] <- rnorm(length(inds), 3, 0.5)

ggplot(airis, aes(x = Species, y = value, fill = Species)) +
    geom_flat_violin(position = position_nudge(x = .15, y = 0)) +
    facet_wrap(~measurement) 

## this second plot shows larger distribution curves for all speceis in the "Petal.Width" panel, although values were only changed for "setosa"
```

[here's a side-by-side image of the data plotted as is, and after adjusting the small values, as done by the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsAeQ.png)

Does anyone know where the problem might be, or what can be done to fix it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "incorrect" / "unexpected" / "is modified somehow" means to you? Perhaps show a picture comparing what you see and what you expected?

Comment: The density curves in some panels are flatter than they should be, so I assumed some modification of the density value had occurred. I have edited the question to hopefully clarify what I mean. The code attached includes plots before and after correction of the shape of the curves to show what they should look like. It is not a solution though because it relies on making up values.